# What are the major pros for docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

As i know, It is just a hub which contains image only, So i can't push on docker hub with docker-compose. However, I can push our repository which contains docker-compose things to github, so that someone who want to execute my source can pull it from github.

Then, they can run command like `docker-compose up`.

I think this is just a good with github or bigbucket.

Is there something more feature i can use or i have to consider with docker hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise is simple: Docker Hub gives us a space to host and manage our Docker images. This way we can delegate all the hard and tedious work to it.
The main purpose of doing this is to separate the container management from the deployment service. Once Docker Hub informs us that our new image has been built correctly, we’re ready to deliver it to whichever service we prefer. This has a huge benefit over traditional methods because separating the image building process from the actual instance means that our application environment will keep running until we do the actual deployment.
But that's not all! Docker Hub also comes with many handy features to make our work easier.
In my opinion, the true star features are these two: 
Autobuild: Docker Hub automatically pulls our code from GitHub or BitBucket, locates the Dockerfile in it and starts building, tagging and pushing the image into the container.
Autotest: Docker Hub starts running our application tests after building the image and allows us to automatically stop the push process if anything fails.
You can get more information about Docker Hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/).

Comment: Docker Hub's primary objective is to manage Docker Images, not containers.

Answer (score 0):

Docker hub is a cloud based repository which helps users to create, share and distribute container images.A user can access the high-quality container images provided by Docker as well as use a space to create their own private repositories, automated build functions, webhooks and work groups.

I think It's a great platform to access the public, open source image repositories.

**One Simple Use Case**: It would also be beneficial in case if you create a cluster using multiple machines and all machines are pointing to the same version of images using docker hub. It would act as a central repositories(source of truth) for your system.

Please follow [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/) to get more insights.